# Is #10 wire correct for my mini-split system on a disconnect?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, 240v

I have a disconnect box that is on a 50 amp breaker connected to a disconnect box using 6 AWG. In order to connect my mini split system to the disconnect do I use 10 AWG wire based on the information on the label?
[image: Mini split label]

Comment: Does your disconnect use fuses or breakers inside it, or is it an unfused disconnect?

Comment: Yes, does your disconnect have fuses in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any wire you want, 10 AWG or larger... so if you have some #6 lying around, don't make a run to the store lol.

As far as circuit breaker, 30A is fine.  What the label is telling you is that if you get nuisance trips, it's OK to bump to 35A or 40A.   Or even 45A, but that is not a commonly made breaker size, so that basically means 40A lol.   It might be available in fuses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use #10 AWG. The minimum circuit capacity per the manufacturer must be followed. You will also have to replace the 50 Amp breaker with a 30 Amp breaker and pigtail the # 6 AWG to a piece of #10 AWG since the #6 won't fit (probably won't) into a 30 AMP breaker.

Comment: I presume the "Max.Fuse 45A" means a maximum 45amp breaker (or fuse), but since those don't seem to be common a 30 or 40am would be appropriate instead of the 50, right?

Comment: Yes,  the manufacturers give an upper and lower limit to what will protect the unit. A 40 AMP breaker would be ok too but then you'd need #8 AWG.

Comment: @JACK Actually in this specific case, you would be allowed to run the 40 amp breaker on #10 AWG. It's allowed because that is what the label calls for. You follow minimum circuit amp (MCA) for wire size, and maximum overcurrent protection (MOP) for breaker size. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/106924/65622 for code reference.

Comment: @PhilippNagel  Old dog still learning stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand the DV.